# Nested WFC DataGrid gives NullReferenceException

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I have a tree-like object structure three levels deep and have tried to represent that in a DataGrid.

I'll show the XAML below, but there is basically a top-level DataGrid, with a DataGridTemplateColumn that contains a ToggleButton. If you click the button it shows the second DataGrid, which has an identical setup. That should allow you to click the ToggleButton in the second grid and show the third (and final) DataGrid.

This is the expected result:

[image]

So you'd click "Destinations..." to show the Destination grid and then click "Expressions..." to show that detail.

Both buttons are implemented with identical code:

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn>
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ToggleButton Content="Destinations..." ButtonBase.Click="ToggleButton_Click" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

If both buttons have their Click handlers assigned (same handler, or different), I get a NullReferenceException when I click "Destinations..." (before the destinations grid even displays).

But if I take out the handler for the "Expressions..." button, everything shows just dandy, but of course you cannot expand the inner grid.

The problem is not with my objects, because if I just leave the grid's RowDetailsVisibilityMode="Visible" data from all three levels reflect in the grid. The problem seems to be isolated to the use of the ButtonBase.Click event on the inner grid.

Here's the XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="SPConvert.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="Stored Procedure Converter" Height="425" Width="705">
    <Grid>
        <DataGrid Name="conversionsGrid" RowDetailsVisibilityMode="Collapsed" CanUserAddRows="False">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn>
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <ToggleButton Content="Destinations..." ButtonBase.Click="ToggleButton_Click" />
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel DockPanel.Dock="Left">
                        <Label Content="Add destination paths" />
                        <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Destinations}" RowDetailsVisibilityMode="Visible">
                            <DataGrid.Columns>
                                <DataGridTemplateColumn>
                                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                                        <DataTemplate>
                                            <ToggleButton Content="Expressions..." ButtonBase.Click="ToggleButton_Click" />
                                        </DataTemplate>
                                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                                </DataGridTemplateColumn>
                            </DataGrid.Columns>
                            <DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Expressions}" AutoGenerateColumns="True">
                                    </DataGrid>
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate>
                        </DataGrid>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate>
        </DataGrid>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

**Update:**
I didn't initially include the code for the click handler, because the exception doesn't occur there. When debugging, I can see the click (of the Destinations button) executing and returning a valid row (and confirm it is the correct row). As long as the event handler for the inner button (Expressions) is not assigned, the row expands just dandy. When that is assigned, I get the error. But keep in mind that the Expressions button is never clicked and I can confirm in the debugger that the handler only executes once.

Here is the code of the click handler:

```
private DataGridRow FindClickedRow(DependencyObject dep)
{
    // dep is the DependencyObject that was clicked. We can then iterate up the visual tree to find the clicked row.
    while ((dep != null) && !(dep is DataGridRow))
        dep = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(dep);
    return dep as DataGridRow;
}

private void ToggleButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    DataGridRow row = FindClickedRow(e.OriginalSource as DependencyObject);
    row.DetailsVisibility = (row.DetailsVisibility == Visibility.Collapsed)?Visibility.Visible:Visibility.Collapsed;
}
```

Comment: Maybe the code of the click handler would be useful?

Comment: Try wrap all handlers to try catch and add trace/debug messages.
Check getters and setters of all properties.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This [link](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/553188/datagrid-in-wpf-4-raises-nullreferenceexception-when-declaring-event-handlers-on-templatecolumns-in-xaml-in-a-datatemplate) describes your problem.

Simply put you cannot attach to event form templates that are inlined in RowDetailsTemplate.

1st solution: move your templates to Control\Window Resources:

```
 <Window.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="innertemplate">
            <ToggleButton Content="Expressions..." ButtonBase.Click="ToggleButton_Click" />
        </DataTemplate>

        <DataTemplate x:Key="template">
            <StackPanel DockPanel.Dock="Left">
                <Label Content="Add destination paths" />
                <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Destinations}" RowDetailsVisibilityMode="Visible">
                    <DataGrid.Columns>
                        <DataGridTemplateColumn CellTemplate="{StaticResource innertemplate}">

                        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
                    </DataGrid.Columns>
                    <DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Expressions}" AutoGenerateColumns="True">
                            </DataGrid>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate>
                </DataGrid>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Window.Resources>
```

and reference it in grid:

```
RowDetailsTemplate="{StaticResource template}"
```

2nd solution: Move content of template to UserControl and add template as:

```
 <DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <local:YourControl />
```

where `local` is in my project `xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1"`

Comment: I went with your first solution and it works perfectly. Thanks! Looks like StackOverflow will only allow me to award the bounty tomorrow, so I'll do it then.